# Print results of MySQL query using JQuery JSON without knowing the names of the array keys

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, symfony

I am building a facility on a website (using Symfony2) that allows the user to create reports and display them on a screen using AJAX. The reports are effectively SQL statements that are created on the fly and are then ran on the Database.

The problem I have is that I can't fathom a way to display these results to the screen without first knowing what fields are used in the report. The queries could contain just 2 fields from a table, or 15 fields, and I'd like the code to be robust enough to handle this.

So far, this is the code I'm using:

```
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: urlLink,
                success: function (data) {
                        var Type = (data.recordType);
                        var Results = (data.results);
                        var Name = (data.name);
                        var Description = (data.description);
                        var Titles = (data.titles);

                        $('#reportName').text(Name);
                        $('#reportDescription').text(Description);

                        $('#listTable > tbody:last').empty();
                        $('#listTable > thead:last').empty();

                        $('#listTable > thead:last').append('<tr>'+Titles+'</tr>');

                        $.each(Results, function(i, item) {
                                $('#listTable > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>' + Results[i] + '</td><td>' + Results[i] + '</td><td>' + Results[i] + '</td><td>' + Results[i] + '</td><td>' + Results[i] + '</td><td>' + Results[i] + '</td></tr>');
                        });
                }
        });
```

The variable `Titles` comes from the query, as when the user is adding fields to the database these are then added to a string which I then explode using PHP in the controller.

Inside the foreach, every column comes back with `[object Object]`. When I remove the `[i]` from the code and replace it with `.column-name` it will then work. But this is what I'm trying to avoid. I'd like to have something similar to what I do with the Table Titles.

Comment: Do you know about `for (var x in a)` javascript syntax?

Comment: I don't, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this, and show output of console.log(data);

```
console.log(data);
var data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Comment: This should be comment, not an answer.

Comment: I can not comment because of the low reputation

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data, function() {
  $.each(this, function(k, v) {
 /// do stuff
});
});
```